# Confusion matrix almost perfectly balanced

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to predict the winning team of a Destiny2 PvP match based on the player stats.
The dataset has multiple columns:

1. **player_X_stat**

- X from 1 to 12 for each player, players from 1 to 6 are in team A and players from 7 to 12 are in team B
- stat is a specific player stat like average number of kills per game or average number of deaths per game etc.
- So there are X * (number of different stat) columns (around 100 at the end)

2. **winning_team** being always 0 (see note below). The winning team is always composed of players from 1 to 6 (team A) and the losing team is composed of players from 7 to 12 (team B).

note: To set up a balanced dataset, I shuffle the teams so that the winning_team column has as many 0s as 1s. For example, player_1_kills becomes player_7_kills, player_7_kills becomes player_1_kills and winning_team becomes 1.

However when training a catboost classifier or a simple SVC, **the confusion matrix is almost perfectly balanced**:

- [[87486 31592]
- [31883 87196]]

It seems to me that this is an anomaly but I have no idea where it could come from.

Edit: [link to google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EC7gD57IQgDWFamMgmr478tb5b7zidhV?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you provide your code? You can use for instance google colab.

Comment: Sure here it is : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EC7gD57IQgDWFamMgmr478tb5b7zidhV?usp=sharing

Comment: After checking your code, I suppose that this result in the confusion matrix might occur because you are using stratified splits. And another thing: isn't catboost for categorical features? As far as I see you have float features.

Comment: Thanks, "CatBoost supports numerical, categorical, text, and embeddings features" and here the only categorical feature I use is "mode" corresponding to a specific gamemode (zone control, mayem etc.).
Without stratified splits, the confusion matrix is still the same (almost perfectly balanced)

Comment: But numerical does not mean float (it might transform the numerical features in a way that they are whole numbers, etc.). Could you check how "balanced" the matrix looks like when you remove some of the features ?

Comment: If I use only the combat_rating stat, the matrix looks like this:
[[79851 39431]
 [38936 79939]]
Furthermore, I tried using xgboost or a simple random forest and the matrix remains balanced (also same acc as catboost).